# Stop background from resizing itself

Tags: java, android, class, layout, resize

So in my application, I'm using the system wallpaper as the background.
I'm doing so with the following code -

```
  WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
  Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
  view.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
```

The problem is, the background is trying to squish inwards. In other words the system image is trying to fit the whole image in one bit and it looks weird. How can I stop the background from resizing itself?

More info, on my homescreen, the wallpaper would be a picture of a car, you can only see the front part of the car. But when you open my app, you can see the full car but its squished and resized.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help (from the [WallpaperManager Class page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html)):

```
 wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(int minimumWidth, int minimumHeight);
```